# Converting a TRRS apple connector to 2 TRS connectors to use on PC

Tags: audio, microphone

What i'm trying to do here is using the in-line microphone of my pair of Sennheiser Urbanite on my pc. For that i bought  a third party splitter (3.5mm 4 Position TRRS Female to 2x 3 Position TRS). The issue though is that it doesn't work and i'm assuming it's because of Apple's non standard pinout, i think they swap the microphone and the ground rings on the 3.5mm jack, which renders my splitter useless (audio works fine though since the wiring is the same). Is there anything i can do to make it work?

Comment: Does everything not work, or do some parts work and others don't? For instance, can you hear audio, but the mic doesn't work, or vice versa? Also, do your headphones use the AHJ or OMTP standard https://help.longtailproducts.com/hc/en-us/articles/207970396-Smartphone-Headset-Standards-Apple-iPhone-AHJ-CTIA-OMTP ? Apple uses a variant of AHS. Same pin-out, but different signaling methods.

Comment: Also, what computer model do you have?

Comment: Audio works just fine but the microphone wont pick up anything. The headphones i'm 99% sure are using AHJ standard. As for the computer, it's a custom made desktop with a simple case but i can open it and double check on how the front panel jacks connect to the motherboard. Might be worth to note that if i connect it on the back directly to the motherboard it also doesn't work, so i'm assuming the front panel jacks are wired the same as the motherboard ones.

Not sure if this is useful information but the spliter i'm using is "Logilink Ca0020"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your headphones are Apple-specific, and will require an adapter capable of adapting the Apple-specific signal paths to the paths and signals the PC expects.

From [this article](https://help.longtailproducts.com/hc/en-us/articles/207970396-Smartphone-Headset-Standards-Apple-iPhone-AHJ-CTIA-OMTP):

> Apple's non-standard signalling and control method means many designed
>   for iPhone headsets are incompatible with other devices. In general
>   the audio out and one button control on such headsets will work, but
>   the audio-in (microphone) and volume controls will not.

Based on the symptoms you describe "Audio works just fine but the microphone wont pick up anything" I'm guessing this is the issue.

The solution will be to find an adapter that notes it that is capable of adapting from the Apple variant of AHJ to the standard TRS.

Comment: Apple and their "innovations" am i right?....